# Application of Radon-Nikodym

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, proof-verification

Let $\nu$ and $\mu$ be two $\sigma$-finite measures on $(X,\mathcal{M})$ and assume that RN holds, with $w = \frac{d\nu}{d\mu}$. Show that, for each non negative measurable function $g$ it holds

$$ \int_X g \, d\nu = \int_X g w \, d\mu $$

Here's my reasoning:

We can assume that $g$ and $w$ are countably-simple, and then the general case will follow by definition of integral. Suppose g assume values $\{a_i\}_{i \in I}$ and $w$ assumes values $\{m_j\}_{j \in J}$ and let $A_i := g^{-1}(\{a_i\})$, $M_j := w^{-1}(\{m_j\})$.

I would write

$$ \int_X g \, d\nu = \sum_{i \in I} a_i \nu(A_i) = \\ = \sum_{i \in I} a_i \int_{A_i} w \, d\mu = \sum_{i \in I} a_i \sum_{j \in J} m_j \mu(M_j \cap A_i)= \\
= \sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in J}  a_i m_j \cdot \mu(M_j \cap A_i) = \int_X g w \, d\mu$$

where the last step is actually just the definition of the integral for countably simple functions (as $g \cdot w$ is still countably simple).

Am I wrong somewhere? there are a bunch of hypotheses I'm not actually using, like the fact that the measures are $\sigma$-finite and that $g$ is non negative...

Comment: Of course, if $g$ is negative, the same holds, and for general we can split $g=g_+ \,+\, g_-$.

Comment: Indeed, if my proof is correct, there should be no need to split $g$, the proof should directly provide the general case…if it is correct!

Comment: The only thing that stands out to me as maybe needing care is that you have approximated $g$ with simple functions with respect to $d\nu$ and you have approximated $w$ with simple functions with respect to $d\mu$, but may be you need to mention a little bit why these approximating sequences also work for $gw \, d\mu$?